# How to close hamburger menu when clicking link

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have created a hamburger menu which slides out form the left. All the links which link to other pages work fine however one link, "contact", links to my `<footer>` on the same page. The correct action takes place behind the menu but the menu does not close so it can't be seen unless I go up to the toggle button and close it.

I have tried `hide`, and `toggle` but the `toggle` button does not return to its initial state (hamburger) nor does anything happen when clicked. Any help appreciated!

```css
#menu__toggle {
  opacity: 0;
}

#menu__toggle:checked+.menu__btn>span {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked+.menu__btn>span::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked+.menu__btn>span::after {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#menu__toggle:checked~.menu__box {
  left: 0 !important;
}

.menu__btn {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu__btn>span,
.menu__btn>span::before,
.menu__btn>span::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgb(201, 199, 199);
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.menu__btn>span::before {
  content: '';
  top: -8px;
}

.menu__btn>span::after {
  content: '';
  top: 8px;
}

.menu__box {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 80px 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ECEFF1;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

.menu__item {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  color: #333;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: .25s;
  text-align: center;
}

.hList {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.menu__item:hover {
  background-color: #CFD8DC;
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger-menu">
  <input id="menu__toggle" type="checkbox" />
  <label class="menu__btn" id="ham__btn" for="menu__toggle">
    <span></span>
  </label>
  <ul class="menu__box">
    <li class="hList"><a class="menu__item" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li class="hList"><a class="menu__item" href="narrative.index.html">Narrative</a></li>
    <li class="hList"><a class="menu__item" href="commercial.index.html">Commercials</a></li>
    <li class="hList"><a class="menu__item" href="promos.index.html">Promos</a></li>
    <li class="hList"><a class="menu__item" id="indexContact" href="index.html#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you'll need to ad a click event handler for that link at least, and close the hamburger menu in the handler `document.querySelectorAll('.special').forEach(l=>l.addEventListener('click',e => document.getElementById('menu__toggle').click()));` (add `special` to the class for links this is for)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Fantastic! Worked perfectly, thank you!